# Excel VBA Polling/ preventing code from running more than once in specified time

Tags: vba, excel

I have another code thats running in the background, and when certain conditions are met it will call the sub Alert. There are multiple scenarios that call this code out though and whats happening right now is Alert starts running more frequently then the 3 seconds I would like it to (indicated by AlertTIMER). Here's my attempt to solve the issue

```
Sub Alert()
If Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
Beep
Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
Beep
Call AlertTIMER
Exit Sub
Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Sub AlertTIMER()
Dim ACountDown As Date
ACountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.OnTime ACountDown, "Alert"
End Sub
```

Clearly it did not work haha. Originally i had one if Statement with or's instead of the ands... but that was not working either. Any help?

**EDIT:**

I believe what is happening is in the AlertTIMER sub it calculates the value ACountDown. In example lets say it is first triggered at 12:00:00 AM ( ACountDown will = 12:00:03 AM) and then submts it to Application.OnTime as that value (12:00:03 AM). When another event is triggered lets say at 12:00:01 AM it calculates ACountDown as 12:00:04 AM and then submits it to Application.OnTime as that value (12:00:04 AM). So in the end I have "Alert" being triggered at 12:00:03 and 12:00:04. One way to solve this would be if the code kept ACountDown as a variable until "Alert" is triggered from Application.OnTime??. So with the previous example it calculates 12:00:03 AM first for ACountDown, but then is reset to 12:00:04 AM when the second trigger comes in. At 12:00:04 AM it then triggers "Alert" via Application.OnTime - only running it once.

EDIT2:

Another way to work around this, if there is a way to accomplish this, would be to check if there is an Application.OnTime running/active if so then cancel it. The code would look like this:

```
Sub AlertTIMER()
Dim ACountDown As Date

If Application.OnTime(, "Alert") Is Nothing Then
Else
 Application.OnTime ACountDown, "Alert", , False
End If

ACountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.OnTime ACountDown, "Alert"
End Sub
```

But `If Application.OnTime(, "Alert") Is Nothing Then` returns an error... as you can't check to see if it is nothing since it's not an object. Any thought on how maybe I could get this to work?

Comment: "*it isn't working*" doesn't tell us anything.  Tell us what's actually happening, and what should be happening.  An example can also be helpful.

Comment: I understand i didn't provide an example... as far as code, but I tried to explain it: "whats happening right now is Alert starts running more frequently then the 3 seconds I would like it to" In other words when Alert is triggered more than once in another code, instead of hearing "Beep*, Part is done, Beep*" wait 3 seconds "Beep*, Part is done, Beep*"... I hear "Beep*, Part is done, Beep*" wait (random seconds less than 3) "Beep*, Part is done, Beep*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub AlertTIMER()

Dim StartTick As Single
Dim CurrTick As Single
Dim EndTick As Single

StartTick = Timer
EndTick = StartTick + ("3.00")
Do
    CurrTick = Timer
    DoEvents
Loop Until CurrTick >= EndTick
Call Alert
End Sub
```

This isn't exactly what I was looking for but it gets the job done I suppose... This allows the "Beep, Part is Done, Beep" to become synced up instead of competing. If AlertTimer is triggered while it has already been triggered previously (waiting for CurrTick to reach EndTick) then EndTick gets reset so now it is only being triggered once.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Sub Alert()

    If Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False And Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton21.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton22.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton25.Enabled = False Then
        Beep
        Application.Speech.Speak ("Part is done")
        Beep
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call AlertTIMER

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe I tried this and it did not work, but I will try this again and let you know. I do not have the code handy right now.

Comment: This did not work, if two of the events triggered then the "Beep, Part is Done, Beep" competed.